# raspberry pi openvpn: ERROR: Cannot open TUN/TAP

Tags: raspberry-pi, openvpn, raspberry-pi4

I'm getting the above error when trying to connect to vpn given a `.ovpn` file. Usually this bug happens after an upgrade occurs and you haven't restarted yet. But I already did and the error still exists. I have tried reinstalling the openvpn (I'm using 2.4.7 on debian) and would not like to use this on docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since getting this error when executing the command `sudo openvpn file.ovpn` often returns vague errors such as the one above, you can produce a more specific error when trying to import the ovpn file into `NetworkManager` instead.

After installing `network-manager` of course:

```sh
nmcli con import type openvpn vpn file.ovpn
```

Connect to the profile:

```sh
nmcli con up id vpn
```

Running this command would immediately show you a clearer error that is something along the lines of the org freedesktop networkmanager vpn plugin being unknown. Which is then solvable by installing the said plugin.

```sh
sudo apt install network-manager-openvpn
```

And that should do it.